# Prefect in a Docker Swarm cluster

Tags: dask, docker-swarm, prefect

We actually use Docker Swarm to manage our cluster.
Some services are scheduled with swarm-cronjob and run at fixed time, but we want more flexibility.

So we decided to give Prefect a chance and it seems promising, but we can not find how or if it is possible for it to work with warm nodes.

A case would be tu run a task, part of a flow, on a dedicated node of the swarm, identified by a specific label.

Are there natively a support for docker swarm, or some experimentations ?
What would be the best way for you to make prefect and docker swarm work together ?
Do we need to use a Dask cluster on top of docker swarm or is there another way ?